# Node.js api not working when deploying to AWS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have one Node.js app and the frontend is using React. When I develope it on my local, I put the project under http://localhost/app subdirectory and api is under `/api`, the port I use is 5000. It's all working. Here is the way I set:

For Node.js, I use this to set the Frontend directory and router:

```
const indexRouter = require('./routers')
app.use('/api', indexRouter)  //to set API path
app.use('/app', express.static('public'))
```

the server is listen on 5000.

For React, I update the package.json to:

```
"homepage": "/app",
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000/"
```

and with the Axios request, I add the base varible at the beginning of the request path and set it to '/api'

This is all good on my localhost. However, when I deploy it to AWS with Nginx, I couldn't make the API request success.

With Nginx, I update the original location block from

```
location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ = 404;
}
```

to

```
location /app {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

When I go to `/root/app`, I can see the homepage of the React (I copied the React build files into the Node js public folder). However, it cannot get the request success. I can see on my localhost, the request path is http://localhost:3050/api/login, but the live sever request path is http://domain_name/login, I don't know why the server cannot go to `/api` for request.

I hope someone can help me for this.

Comment: Did you build your react app before deploying to production? using npm or yarn?

Comment: Yes. I created the React app by create-react-app, then run yarn run build to create the build folder and copy these files all into the public folder of Node js.

Answer (score 0):

Since you built the React app using yarn build, you would not be able to use the proxy that you were using in the development. That method is for testing in development only, and not in production. You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1087#issuecomment-262611096).

Comment: Yes, I know proxy is only working on dev environment. That's why I set nginx reverse proxy. However, it's not working yet.